# Windows 10 can not be woken up from the keyboard if it sleeps for a while?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, sleep, wake-up

I installed a windows 10 desktop recently which goes to sleep after a while if not used. The user reported that he left the computer there for a while and when he got back, simply pressing a key on the USB keyboard did not wake the computer up. He needed to press the power button.

I tested sleep when I was there it worked properly, I was able to wake the computer by pressing any key on the keyboard. ((I made it to sleep and woke it up right after that.)

Why is it that after a longer sleep the user could only wake the computer up with the power button, instead pressing a key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might arise from the power plan options that allow
[Hybrid Sleep](https://www.maketecheasier.com/hybrid-sleep-on-windows/)
to pass into hibernate after a certain time.

Check for it this way:

- Open Power Options from the Start menu
- On your power plan, click *Change plan settings*
- In Edit Plan Settings, click *Change advanced power settings*
- In Advanced settings, open the branch of Sleep
- Either set "Allow hybrid sleep" to Never, or set "Hibernate after"
  to a longer time
- Click OK
- Reboot might be required

[image]

Comment: Hibernate was off. I turned off hybrid sleep now, though I thought it is for power cuts only, in case the computer would lose the sleep state. I saw no setting there to control the transition time from sleep to hibernation.

Comment: I added an image of mine.

Comment: Yes, I turned off hybrid. But I see no option to control the transition time from sleep to hibernate, so it's etiher completely off or on, though it would be useful to transition from to sleep to hibernate after 2 hours or so.

Comment: Strange. In Device Manager, right click on the keyboard or mouse, Properties, Power Management tab, is "Allow this device to wake computer " checked? What is your computer exact model?

Comment: I'm not there right now, so I can't check, but I'll check it. It must be the default setting, because it's a fresh install and I haven't changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that after first being on sleep, somehow the electric supply got cut(any reason) and hence it would only start by the power key.

Or the PC went into hibernation...it stays at sleep for some time but then goes into hibernation....so longer sleep induces hibernation.

Comment: There were no power cuts. Would hibernation prevent waking up from usb keyboard? Isn't there be a hardware wake up event for USB?

Comment: yes hibernation would prevent waking up from usb keyboard...i just tried it on my desktop. I dont think so that there is any wake up event for USB from hibernation because the whole point of sleep vs hibernation is to turn off the computer entirely while it is in hibernation ...instead of RAM the contents are saved on the secondary storage devices such as HDD of the PC. So you could unplug your hibernated PC and still lose no data.

Comment: Apparently there is an option to wake from hibernate too with mouse/keyboard, so it is supported: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/102807-how-wake-hibernation-only-through-power-button.html

Comment: @Tom On my desktop.."Allow this device to wake the computer" is enabled but still the keyboard only wakes up the computer from Sleep and not from Hibernation.

Comment: OK, I haven't tried it, just googled it and linked to the discussion I found. There are others too: https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/33596-pc-wakes-hibernation-mouse-keyboard.html

Comment: probably it depends on your hardware/bios if it supports it